# Android: How do I implement a pin lock, (get name of system wide top activity)

Tags: android

I have an activity running. Here's a use case that I'm having trouble solving. When a user leaves my activity (meaning a screen that IS NOT a part of my activity - say pressing the home key) and then returns to my activity, I want to implement a lock where the user has to enter a pin to resume.

Example: My Activity -> User presses home -> User long presses home and sees my activity in th e recent task list -> User presses my activity -> and my activity comes up to a pin screen.

I have no way of detecting what the current top activity THAT DOES NOT BELONG TO MY APPLICATION. I want to get the package name of the top activity no matter what it is.

This code:
        String pkgName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

Always returns the top activity of MY activity. I don't want this.

Is there any way to retrieve the name of the top activity system wide?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that top activity?? Isn't the problem about implementing the pin lock??

I assume you should try implement OnPause() and OnResume() 
tutorial how to od it is [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html) ;-)

Comment: I am implementing onResume(). When I ask for the top activity in my onresume, i get the name of the activity in MY APP, and not the home.